# Setting a calling convention for std::function

Tags: c++, stl, calling-convention

I'm very new to using std and I'm currently trying to call into a function that takes an std::function as a param. Something similar to below:

In the .h file in one lib:

```
typedef bool t (/*Params*/);

void __stdcall Foo(std::function<t> &function) {m_function = function;}

std::function<t> m_function;
```

I imported the lib and tried to use Foo in another cpp file:

```
bool Implementation (/*Params*/)
{
   // Implementation
}

void Bar()
{
    Foo(std::function<t> (Implementation));
}
```

I'm getting a linker error (LNK2019) when I compile for x86 (but not x64) because of the calling convention:

```
Unresolved External Symbol __stdcall Foo (class std::tr1::function<bool __cdecl(/*Params*/) const&)
```

From this I gathered that I need to mark "t" and Implementation as __stdcall but doing so causes other compile failures. I should also note the code compiled correctly when it was being built in the same lib. Is there a way to associate a calling convention to an std::function?

Comment: Considering you said the 64-bit version works, first check that you  are linking the correct version of the library (32-bit).

Comment: The library is linked correctly (and is resolving the other functions properly). I think the issue has more to do with x64 having a much simpler calling convention story.

Comment: One more thing to note about the functions that are exporting properly is that I was able to assign them a calling convention where as when I try to add a calling convention to my type def (or within an std::function I get a functional error.

Comment: The error is telling you that you have no definition of `Foo`, just a declaration in the header file.  You need definition for `Foo` somewhere (in your library?) and you need to link against that.

Comment: I realized that the code I had above was a little misleading. I actually did have the definition of Foo in the header. All Foo does is set a member variable. I will correct this above.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
void Foo(const std::function<bool()> &func)
{
  func();
}

bool Implementation (/*Params*/)
{
  cout << "Implementation"<<endl;
  return true;
}

void Bar()
{
    Foo(std::function<bool()>(&Implementation));
}

int main()
{
  Bar();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried some of your suggestions (removed the typedef and passed &implementation instead of implementation) and I ended up with the same error. I also tried creating a pointer for stdcall explicitly and passing that and it continues to look for cdecl. I'm going to try dumping the lib next and taking a peek and what its exporting the function as.